# Retrieve data from cube using several members of the same dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am trying to retrieve the data from a cube, the problem that I have is that I need to select several members from the same dimension, among other dimensions from the cube.  I tried using a member concatenation in the MDX query like this:

```
with member 
[DIMTIME].[NEWDATE] as [DIMTIME].[DIMTIME].properties("day")+" "+[DIMTIME].[DIMTIME].properties("month")+" "+[DIMTIME].[DIMTIME].properties("year")
select non empty{
[Measures].[COUNT]
on columns,
[DIMTIME].[NEWDATE] on rows
from [SAMPLE]
```

But I get an error because I am using several times DIMTIME. I am trying to get the other dimensions values, but want to retrieve all dates.  Do you have an idea of how to do this?

What I would like to have as a result is something like this:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6GHy.png)

Where the NEW_DATE is the concatenation of the day_month_year, and it is also grouped by the other dimensions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will be shocked if your date dimension doesn't have a single attribute that has the formatted date. If not, and you can change the design, then this is the right way to do it. Just add a date attribute to your dimension and use this attribute rather than accessing day, month and year attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you are trying to achieve.

In MS's AdvWrks we just do this:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It then gives this result:

[image]

In AdvWrks the Date dimension looks like this:

[image]

I think you need to work on your cube structure